# conditional of a conditional

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have random variables $x,y,z$. Let $(x\mid y)$ denote a random variable whose distribution is the conditional distribution of $x$ given $y$. (Is there a standard notation for this object?) I would like to prove something like:
$$
(x\mid y) \mid (z\mid y) = (x\mid y,z)
$$
This seems intuitively true, but I'm having trouble proving it formally. I'm also not entirely sure that the notation I introduced even makes sense. I'm familiar with the law of total expectation, and this is similar, but I want a statement about the distributions, not just their conditional expectations.

Comment: The notation is:  $p(x|y,z) = p(x|y) p(x|z)$.  Every book on probability will discuss the conditions for this to hold.

Comment: $(x\mid y)$ is not an event in the original probability space.  So it is difficult to describe it let alone find a notation for it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork did you intend to say $p(x\mid y,z) {p(z\mid y)}={p(x,z\mid y)}$ ?  I would have thought $p(x\mid y,z)=p(x\mid y)p(x\mid z)$ looks unlikely

Comment: In case it wasn't clear in my post, there is a vertical bar between (x|y) and (z|y). So I actually want to condition (x|y) on (z|y).

Comment: Conditional random variables is about $\sigma$-algebras. When you say $(x|y)$, you are conditioning $x$ to the $\sigma$-algebra induced by $y$. But the $\sigma$-algebra of $(z|y)$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of that induced by $z$. So, I guess your conclusion is false.